# Python pywintypes.com_error occurs on one server but not another

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an application running on a new server which is raising some odd unicode-related errors that we've never seen before, for certain characters (e.g. *S with Caron*) but not others (e.g., *e with umlaut*). The application has successfully handled unicode characters including the *S with Caron* for the duration of its lifetime on Server A (approximately 4 years).  Now migrating to Server B, I am seeing these errors and not sure how to resolve.

Because the code base is the same in both locations and we have not seen this error on Server A, only now on the (new) Server B, I'm thinking this isn't a problem in the code itself, but rather some configuration on the Servers.

## Background

Both servers running Python 2.7, Server A running Windows Server 2008 R2 and Server B running Windows Server 2012 R2. The new server is running SPSS Dimensions v7 whereas the old server is running Dimensions v6, so there are a lot of moving parts here.

The Python application reads metadata from an SPSS Statistics file and passes it to a COM Object (another IBM object type) via the object's `AddNew` method:

```
table = self.tom.Tables.AddNew("Table" + iTable, sideAxis + u" * " + topAxis)
```

The `topAxis` contains the unicode string: `škoda` which is passed correctly on Server A:

```
'škoda'
```

While Server B is attempting to pass the following instead:

```
'\u0161koda'
```

## Traceback

This seems to indicate that the `Tables.AddNew` method is receiving something it can't handle. The *S with Caron*, `U+0160` is raising an error on Server B, as the identifier `\u0161koda` is not present in the SAV file. **I don't understand why it's happening on one server but not the other.**

```
File "D:\chartbuilder\versions\2.3\tigertom.py", line 1824, in CreateTable
    table = self.tom.Tables.AddNew("Table" + iTable, sideAxis + u" * " + topAxis)
File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 3, in AddNew
File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 287, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, u"The expression 'qj_make * {\u0161koda}' is not valid: Unknown category '\u0161koda'", None, 0, -2147352570), None)
```

## Add'l Diagnostics

On both environments, `topAxis` appears to be instance of basestring & unicode:

```
2017-05-24 13:56:48.755||INFO||topAxis is basestring: True 
2017-05-24 13:56:48.755||INFO||topAxis is unicode: True
```

On both Servers I can print to console via and write the expression to a log file:

```
print topAxis.encode('utf-8',errors='backslashreplace')
self.logger.info(u"top axis\n{}\n\t".format(topAxis))
```

Log File on Server A:

[image]

Log File on Server B:[image]

Console print from Server A:

[image]

Console print on Server B:

[image]

Since the code works as expected on Server A, but not on Server B, I am trying to determine the root cause, and hoping it is a server configuration and not a bug in IBM's source code.

I am also able to replicate the error on a laptop with Dimensions 7 installed.

## Questions

1. Am I correct to assume this is an error related to the particular COM Object that is receiving the data?
2. Apart from the obvious version differences, is there anything configuration-wise on the server itself (I'm punching above my weight class here, but possibly pertaining to codepage, stdout/stdin, etc.?) that could cause or contribute to this sort of error?

Comment: If you open a console on each server (using the same user as for the script), what is the code page? Use the [Chcp](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733037(v=ws.11).aspx) command.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE active code page is 437 on both. `sys.stdout.encoding` also shows `'cp437'`.